# Is it possible to add labels to each data point in correlation plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

Im doing a correlation plot between goverment trust and happiness score on nations by continent. I would like to add the correspondent country name to each data point, how could I do that? My code for the plot is this:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6, 4)
sns.scatterplot(x=df_sasia["Trust"],y=df_sasia["Happiness Score"], data=df_seasia,s=80)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach (labels next to the scatter points):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
 
# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
'x': [1, 1.5, 3, 4, 5],
'y': [5, 15, 5, 10, 2],
'group': ['A','other group','B','C','D']
})
 
# basic plot
p1=sns.regplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", fit_reg=False, marker="o", 
               color="blue", scatter_kws={'s':400})
 
    
def add_label(row, shift_x=0.2):
     p1.text(row.x+shift_x, row.y, row.group, 
             horizontalalignment='left', size='medium',
             color='grey', weight='semibold')
        
# add annotations one by one with a loop
for r in range(0, len(df)):
    add_label(df.iloc[r])
```

Another approach is to directly plot the label at (x,y):

```
#create a new figure and set the x and y limits
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
axes.set_xlim(0.5,5.5)
axes.set_ylim(-2,16)

#loop through data points and plot each point 
for l, row in df.iterrows():
    
        #add the data point as text
        plt.annotate(row['group'], 
                     (row['x'], row['y']),
                     horizontalalignment='center',
                     verticalalignment='center',
                     size=11,
                     color='green')
```